# Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: user/*out*

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm currently reading the Clojure Programming book, and following the examples. However I come across an error.

```
(defn print-logger
  [writer]
   #(binding [*out* writer]
      (println %)))

(def *out*-logger (print-logger *out*))

(*out*-logger "hello")
```

Will result in: `Can't dynamically bind non-dynamic var: user/*out*

I'm very new to Clojure, and don't understand why this happens, especially when I'm following the example :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is not in the code sample you have.

`*out*` should refer to `clojure.core/*out*`, so if you are running this in a repl you might have run something previous, to what you have, like `(def *out* something)` to create a `user/*out*`.

Then, when you defined your `print-logger` function, the `(binding [*out* writer] ...)` statement would be trying to rebind `user/*out*` instead of `clojure.core/*out*`.

You can use [`ns-unmap`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/ns-unmap) to remove `user/*out*` from your namespace.

```
(ns-unmap 'user '*out*) ;; => nil
```

You will also need to define your `print-logger` function again to recapture the correct `clojure.core/*out*`.